# How to get current Connection object in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc

How can I get the current Connection object for an Oracle database?  I'm using the JDBC module in Spring 3.0.5.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Obtain the `Connection` from the `DataSource` bean.

You can access the dataSource by using Spring dependency injection to inject it into your bean, or by accessing `ApplicationContext` statically:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("dataSource");
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: But it doesn't return current connection but new connection. I need to return current connection. Situation is: I created connection and i need it to use in another place but in same connection

Comment: How did you create the connection? Please paste the source.

Comment: I created connection using instance of Spring JDBC template

Comment: JDBCTemplate internally uses `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` each time you run one of its methods. It doesn't keep a reference to the connection used last time, so I don't think there is a way to get it.

Comment: @vlcik Please share.

Answer (score 34):

Just an Info : 
I am using Spring JDBC Template, which holds the current connection object for me, which can be received as follows.

```
Connection con;
con = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection();
```

Comment: For those that may not know, a `JdbcTemplate` can be injected as field easily: `@Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;`

Comment: conn must be closed after you use it, or you need to create spring transaction and use DataSourceUtils.getConnection()

Answer (score 29):

Use `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()`.

It returns connection associated with the current transaction, if any.

Comment: I don't use transaction. Your piece of code above creates another instance of connection and it's problem for me. I need current instance which i created sooner

Comment: @user330847: If so, what do you mean by "current connection" and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to call Oracle stored procedure. I successfully created connection by 
creating JDBC template instance. After that I execute callable statement and 
it return me Result Set. Now, I'd like to parse result set and map it to 
value object. And in this process of parsing I need to get connection which was 
created in begining. This connection is 'current connection'. I do not know how
to get this current connection

Comment: @user330847: Why do you need the same connection, if you don't need to share transaction associated with that connection?

Comment: This method doesn't exist in Spring 5.

Comment: It [seems to exist](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceUtils.html#getConnection-javax.sql.DataSource-), @OrangeDog

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this method was available when this question was originally posted, however, it seems the preferred way to do it in the latest version of Spring is with `JdbcTemplate` and `PreparedStatementCreator`.  See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor- or any of the other `query` methods that take a `PreparedStatementCreator` as the first param:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(con -> {
  // add required logic here
  return con.prepareStatement("sql");
 }, rs -> {
       //process row
});
```

This has the advantage over the other provided answers (`DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` or `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()` as a new connection is **not** allocated, it uses the same connection management it would as calling any of the other `jdbcTemplate` querying methods.  You also therefore do not need to worry about closing / releasing the connection, since spring will handle it.