# Oracle/Java Deadlocks while passing ARRAY to stored proc

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, stored-procedures, deadlock

I'm having deadlock in this function. This function is getting called from multiple threads
I have deadlock in this line

```
Map<String,Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(map);   //deadlock here
```

Read article for very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872561/deadlocks-while-passing-array-to-stored-proc) but did not understand if it worked or not and what has to be changed

Can you help me ? how I need to change my code to avoid deadlock

```
public Status validateElementDetails(DetailsInfo[] elementDetails)
    {

        StructDescriptor structDescriptor=null; 
        ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor=null;

        Object[] arrObj =null; 
        Object[][] recObj =null; 
        Connection conn=null; 
        Status status = new Status();

        try{
        log.info("Creating SimpleJdbcCall. dataSource:"+dataSource);
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);

        log.info("Creating connection ...");
        //conn = simpleJdbcCall.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection(); //tried this - deadlock
        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource); //try this
        OracleConnection oraConn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn;
        log.info("Main conn:"+conn);
        log.info("Oracle conn:"+oraConn);

        log.info("Creating structDescriptor ...");
        structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(KEY_CIRCUIT, oraConn);
        log.info("Creating arrayDescriptor ...");
        arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(KEY_CIRCUIT_ARRAY, oraConn);

        log.info("structDescriptor:"+structDescriptor);
        log.info("arrayDescriptor:"+arrayDescriptor);

        log.info("Desc created for Site");
        int iSize = elementDetails.length;

        arrObj = new Object[iSize]; 
        recObj = new Object[iSize][7]; // 4 attributes for validation + 3 for attribute update
        int  size =0;

        for (int j = 0; j < elementDetails.length ;j++)
        {
            SiteDetailsInfo ob = (SiteDetailsInfo)elementDetails[j];

                     recObj[size][0]=ob.getSiteId();
                     recObj[size][1]=ob.getSiteName();
                     recObj[size][2]="";
                     //arrObj[size] = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, conn.getMetaData().getConnection(), recObj[size]);

                     arrObj[size] = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, oraConn, recObj[size]);
                     log.info("recObj ["+size+"]="+recObj[size]);
                     log.info("arrObj ["+size+"]="+arrObj[size]);
                     size++;
          }
        //ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, conn.getMetaData().getConnection(), arrObj);
        log.info("Creating arr ...");
        ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, oraConn, arrObj);
        log.info("Creating arr done:"+arr);
        log.info("SQL object created for validation");

        simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(BGWConstants.KEY_PACKAGE).withProcedureName(BGWConstants.KEY_VALIDATE_SITE_PROC)
        .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("P_SITE_DATA",java.sql.Types.ARRAY,KEY_CIRCUIT_ARRAY))
        .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(BGWConstants.KEY_STATUS_MESSAGE,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
        .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter(BGWConstants.KEY_STATUS,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR));

        log.info("simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName:"+BGWConstants.KEY_VALIDATE_SITE_PROC);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("P_SITE_DATA", arr);    

        log.info("Going to execute DB validation for Site");
        Map<String,Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(map);   //here we have deadlock
        log.info("Going to execute DB validation for Site done");

         String dbMessage = (String) out.get(BGWConstants.KEY_STATUS_MESSAGE);
         String dbStatus = (String) out.get(BGWConstants.KEY_STATUS);

         if(dbStatus != null && dbStatus.equals("1"))
         {
             status.setMessage(dbMessage);
             status.setStatusCode(StatusCode.SUCCESS);
         }else{
             status.setMessage(dbMessage);
             status.setStatusCode(StatusCode.ERROR);
         }

         log.info("Stored procedure executed with status: "+status.getStatusCode().getValue());

     }catch (Exception e) {

         status.setStatusCode(StatusCode.ERROR);
         status.setMessage("Error while doing Site validation. "+e.getMessage());
         log.error("Exception:"+e.getMessage());
         log.error("Exception:",e);

    } 
        finally{
           try {
                 if (conn != null){ 
                  conn.close();
                  log.info("Connection from jdbcTemplate is closed");
                 }
           } catch (SQLException e2) {
               log.info("problem while closing connection");
           }
    }

        return status;      
    }
```

Here is the log

```
[deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thread '[ACTIVE] [b]ExecuteThread: '14' [/b]for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@[b]42cb6b0a' [/b]that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''
[code]
Stack trace:
------------
        oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.getName(TypeDescriptor.java:703)
        oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION.isInHierarchyOf(OracleTypeCOLLECTION.java:149)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2063)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3571)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3677)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
        weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:99)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:987)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:368)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:353)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:160)
        com.bgw.dao.SiteDAOImpl.validateElementDetails(SiteDAOImpl.java:311)
        com.bgw.dao.SiteDAOImpl.updateAllSites(SiteDAOImpl.java:139)
        com.bgw.intf.UpdateBGWDBServiceImpl.updateComponentAttributes(UpdateBGWDBServiceImpl.java:154)
        com.bgw.webservices.l1c.BGWDBComponent.BGWDBComponentSOAPImpl.updateComponentAttributes(BGWDBComponentSOAPImpl.java:34)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)

[deadlocked thread] [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)':
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Thread '[ACTIVE] [b]ExecuteThread: '9'[/b] for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'' is waiting to acquire lock 'oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@[b]942f772[/b]' that is held by thread '[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)''

[code]
Stack trace:
------------
        oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.getName(TypeDescriptor.java:703)
        oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION.isInHierarchyOf(OracleTypeCOLLECTION.java:149)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2063)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3571)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3677)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
        weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:99)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$5.doInCallableStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:987)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:936)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:985)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.executeCallInternal(AbstractJdbcCall.java:368)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcCall.doExecute(AbstractJdbcCall.java:353)
        org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SimpleJdbcCall.java:160)
        com.bgw.dao.SiteDAOImpl.validateElementDetails(SiteDAOImpl.java:311)
        com.bgw.dao.SiteDAOImpl.updateAllSites(SiteDAOImpl.java:139)
        com.bgw.intf.UpdateBGWDBServiceImpl.updateComponentAttributes(UpdateBGWDBServiceImpl.java:154)
        com.bgw.webservices.l1c.BGWDBComponent.BGWDBComponentSOAPImpl.updateComponentAttributes(BGWDBComponentSOAPImpl.java:34)
        sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please post source code of `new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)` class.

Comment: SimpleJdbcCall is standard Spring class, nt my class

Comment: @bogdatov did you fix this issue