# How to pass current Connection from Spring context to iReport?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I want to get the current connection from Spring context and then pass to my JasperPrint object.

Something like this:

```
 //java.sql.Connection con = StringContext.getConnection();
 JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport("reports/my_report.jasper", parameters, con);
```

How can I make this works?

ps: I've tried using DataSourceUtils, but the getConnection() method needs a DataSource object as parameter, where do I get this object?

Comment: Use the `DataSourceUtils`, but I would suggest taking a look at the Jasper support in Spring which might give you some other insights.

Comment: @M.Deinum , but how to do that? The DataSourceUtils.getConnection() method needs a DataSource parameter, where do I get this parameter?

Comment: You can just inject the `DataSource` in the class you are creating the `JasperPrint` from (I'm assuming that that is a spring managed class).

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like this:

```
@Component
class JRExporter{
    @Autowired
    protected DataSource localDataSource;

    public void export(){
      java.sql.Connection con = localDataSource.getConnection()
      JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport("reports/my_report.jasper", parameters, con);
    }
```

Comment: but the JRExporter must be  Spring component

Comment: I'm  using Hikari Datasource and when I autowire the datasource as shown then getConnection() it gives me a connection leak error every time I tun the report

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the connection of the current transaction (as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8428795/6230007), using `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()`

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext; 
...

JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport("my_report.jasper", params,
DataSourceUtils.getConnection((DataSource)applicationContext.getBean("dataSource")));
```