# How to get current Connection object used by jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am looking for a way to intercept the connection that JDBCTemplate creates internally i.e. the connection that is created when the function `getConnection()` is called by JDBCTemplate.

ex: if I use `jdbcTemplate.update(query);` I want to get the information of the connection that was used to complete this update statement. Is there a way to see the metadata of the connection mid or post execution of this statement ? I am using C3P0 connection pool.

Many people have suggested using `DataSourceUtils.getConnection()` , but that just fetches a new connection from the pool and does not solve my issue.

This thread also effectively asks the same question: [How to get current Connection object in Spring JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428235/how-to-get-current-connection-object-in-spring-jdbc)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ConnectionCallback-, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ConnectionCallback.html

Answer (score 5):

```
jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

By using the above line we can fetch the connection object.

Comment: that would return *a* connection, but would that be the same connection that the jdbcTemplate uses for its next operation?

Comment: If you get a connection in this way, it will generate a connection leak, so you have to close it manually. 

If you use DataSourceUtils.getConnection() and you are in spring transaction context you will get a same transaction as when you call jdbcTemplate.